# How do I add additional value to my list item

Tags: java, list, spinner

I want to make "over 90", A. "80~90" B and so on, but I find it hard to do that. 
What I'm basically trying to do here is selecting rough score range on spinner and show the users what grade they will get with that score range.

helllp

```
 public void addItemsOnSpinner3(){
    spinner3 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner2);
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    list.add("90 and up");
    list.add("80~90");
    list.add("70~80");
    list.add("60~70");
    list.add("less than 60");
 ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, list);
    dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinner2.setAdapter(dataAdapter);


}


public void addListenerOnButton() {

    spinner1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
    spinner2 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner2);
    enter = (Button) findViewById(R.id.enter);

    enter.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
                            "\nMath : " + String.valueOf(spinner1.getSelectedItem()) +
                            "\nEnglish : " + String.valueOf(spinner2.getSelectedItem()) +
                            "\nScience : " + String.valueOf(spinner3.getSelectedItem()),
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

    });
}
```

}

This is part of my code. What should I change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dont use a list, use a dictionary!

```
Map<string,string> list = new HashMap<string,string>()
list.put("90 and up", "A");
etc
```

to get the Key values (The first in the puts) use:

```
list.keySet();
```

To get your grade use

```
 list.get("90 and up")
```

and the result will be "A"